# Parsing version from Cargo.toml

Tags: parsing, file, rust

I want to get `version` from `Cargo.toml` and use the value inside my app. Here is a function I wrote:

```
use std::fs;

pub fn get_version() -> &'static str {
    let text = fs::read_to_string("Cargo.toml").unwrap();
    for line in text.split("\n") {
        if line.starts_with("version") {
            let start = line.find('"').unwrap() + 1;
            let end = line.rfind('"').unwrap();
            let version = &line[start..end];
            return Box::leak(version.to_string().into_boxed_str());
        }
    }

    panic!("failed parsing version from Cagro.toml");
}
```

Writting the function, I had some questions. So I'd like to get help from others.

- How can I replace `for` and `if` nested blocks with iterator methods?
- To return value as `static` lifetime, I used `Box::leak(version.to_string().into_boxed_str())` which is too complicated (`&str -> String -> Box<str>` just for avoiding compile errors). How can I return `&'static str` or `&'a str` simply without getting `cannot return value referencing local variable ...` error in this case?
- Can I make the code simpler? (ex: parsing the version value)

Comment: Do you know about macro [env!](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html#environment-variables-cargo-sets-for-crates)?

Comment: @aSpex Thanks for the information. I can easily get Cargo version via `env!`. Apart from it, I'd like to get my code reviewed.